# Error cross-compiling binutils-gdb for windows

Tags: makefile, gdb, cross-compiling, binutils

I cloned `binutils-gdb` repository from here (master branch) on a linux machine (Ubuntu) and I want to compile it for Windows (using `x86_64_w64_mingw32` toolchain).

First, I ran `./configure` with the following options to specify the cross-compile toolchain.

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=arm-none-eabi --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32
```

Then I ran `make` and get the following error (I omitted most of the output because it is pretty large):

```
[...]
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -DWITH_DEFAULT_ALIGNMENT=STRICT_ALIGNMENT     -DDEFAULT_INLINE=0   -Wall -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wpointer-arith -Wpointer-sign -Wno-unused -Wunused-value -Wunused-function -Wno-switch -Wno-char-subscripts -Wmissing-prototypes -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wempty-body -Wmissing-parameter-type -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wno-format -Werror  -DMODET -I. -I. -I../common -I./../common -I../../include -I./../../include -I../../bfd -I./../../bfd -I../../opcodes -I./../../opcodes -I../../intl -g -O2     -c -o callback.o -MT callback.o -MMD -MP -MF .deps/callback.Tpo ./../common/callback.c
./../common/callback.c: In function ‘os_time’:
./../common/callback.c:417:25: error: passing argument 1 of ‘time’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
  417 |   return wrap (p, time (t));
      |                         ^
      |                         |
      |                         long int *
In file included from ./../common/callback.c:35:
/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/time.h:230:47: note: expected ‘time_t *’ {aka ‘long long int *’} but argument is of type ‘long int *’
  230 | static __inline time_t __CRTDECL time(time_t *_Time) { return _time64(_Time); }
      |                                       ~~~~~~~~^~~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make[3]: *** [Makefile:513: callback.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/media/D/Work/FC/binutils-gdb/sim/arm'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:928: all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/media/D/Work/FC/binutils-gdb/sim'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:8376: all-sim] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/media/D/Work/FC/binutils-gdb'
make: *** [Makefile:915: all] Error 2
```

I think it has something to do with `time_t` being typedef'd as a `long long int` (64 bit integer) in the host platform (Windows), however, the function `os_time` from the file `sim/common/callback.c:414` (path relative to project root), takes a `long` (32 bit integer) as a parameter:

```c
static long
os_time (host_callback *p, long *t)
{
  return wrap (p, time (t));
}
```

How can I fix this error? Or are there any issue trackers for `binutils-gdb`?

Comment: Are they any specific reasons why 2.36.1 (released around 2021-02-06), would not be recent enough that you would need a more recent version ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are building the current, non-release,development version - I got the exact same error while building from the latest git revision at the time I cloned the repository, `0a703a4cedffa6f3824e87f115e8d392e32de191`.

If you really want to build from the development tree, you will have to wait for the issue to be fixed, or to fix it by yourself - this is not being addressed in this answer.

But if building the latest released version, 2.36.1, is sufficient, the procedure hereafter will work (tested on Ubuntu 20.04 TLS):

```
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/binutils/binutils-2.36.1.tar.gz
tar zxf binutils-2.36.1.tar.gz
mkdir binutils
cd binutils
../binutils-2.36.1/configure --prefix=$(pwd)/binutils-2.36.1-x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=arm-none-eabi --program-prefix=arm-none-eabi- --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32
make
make install
ll -gG binutils-2.36.1-x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/
total 159144
drwxrwxr-x 2     4096 Apr  7 14:41 ./
drwxrwxr-x 6     4096 Apr  7 14:41 ../
-rwxr-xr-x 1  9212998 Apr  7 14:41 arm-none-eabi-addr2line.exe*
-rwxr-xr-x 2  9748961 Apr  7 14:41 arm-none-eabi-ar.exe*
-rwxr-xr-x 2 14457348 Apr  7 14:41 arm-none-eabi-as.exe*
-rwxr-xr-x 1  9077841 Apr  7 14:41 arm-none-eabi-c++filt.exe*
-rwxr-xr-x 1   816086 Apr  7 14:41 arm-none-eabi-elfedit.exe*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 10783524 Apr  7 14:41 arm-none-eabi-gprof.exe*
-rwxr-xr-x 4 14526998 Apr  7 14:41 arm-none-eabi-ld.bfd.exe*
-rwxr-xr-x 4 14526998 Apr  7 14:41 arm-none-eabi-ld.exe*
-rwxr-xr-x 2  9259673 Apr  7 14:41 arm-none-eabi-nm.exe*
-rwxr-xr-x 2 10655762 Apr  7 14:41 arm-none-eabi-objcopy.exe*
-rwxr-xr-x 2 14908446 Apr  7 14:41 arm-none-eabi-objdump.exe*
-rwxr-xr-x 2  9748961 Apr  7 14:41 arm-none-eabi-ranlib.exe*
-rwxr-xr-x 2  6156460 Apr  7 14:41 arm-none-eabi-readelf.exe*
-rwxr-xr-x 1  9193640 Apr  7 14:41 arm-none-eabi-size.exe*
-rwxr-xr-x 1  9190290 Apr  7 14:41 arm-none-eabi-strings.exe*
-rwxr-xr-x 2 10655762 Apr  7 14:41 arm-none-eabi-strip.exe*
```

I did not test building from the git repository after having checked-out the `binutils-2_36_1` tag:

```
git -C binutils-gdb checkout binutils-2_36_1
```

But it should work, if what was tagged is what was packaged in the archive file, which should be the case.

Comment: Hi @Stepii if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is of course no obligation to do this.

Comment: Definitely, 2.36.1 worked. However, now I'm stuck with another error

Comment: 1) One general remark: you should not never  images of text messages in a question/comment but just simply copy/paste the text in a stackoverflow question/comment.
2) I think this is a brand new question, you should have mentioned  first that you were trying to build another software package. I would therefore suggest you to ask a new, specific question. Please do not forget to  point to the source code, and to provide the commands you used for building the software.

Comment: If you want a GUI front-end to GDB, you may have a look at  GDB  TUI mode,  Eclipse CDT with GDB hardware support, or at the Eclipse standalone debugger. Insight is not being maintained anymore I guess.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention that I was trying to compile insight debugger. I have just asked another question. Thank you!